# Why does Dr. Lecter mention Dr. Chilton as Buffalo Bill?

Tags: the-silence-of-the-lambs

The scene is shot after Dr. Lecter was moved out of his cell to meet with Sen. Martin. Clarice then meets him one last time at the state prison in Tennessee. She wants to know the real name of Buffalo Bill. He said, "*Dr. Chilton, I presume*" when Clarice wanted the real name for the last time. It is **not clear to me the logic** behind using Dr. Chilton's name with Buffalo Bill by Dr. Lecter.

Can anyone help me with this part?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the following video, you have the scene you mention. Note what Lecter is doing: he pauses for a moment, closes his eyes to focus on another sense (smell) then catches the scent of a perfume. He then recognizes Dr. Chilton's. That's why he says his name, knowing he was coming and that he was close to him. He's directly addressing Dr Chilton. It's not related to Bill.

He did the same with Clarice's perfume earlier in the movie.<sup>1.</sup>

<sup>1. Lecter: You use *Evian* skin cream, and sometimes you wear *L'Air du Temps*, but not today. [video](https://youtu.be/SoZ1e5kjjcs?t=164)</sup>

Comment: And, in case it's not already crystal clear: when he says “Dr Chilton, I presume”, he's no longer talking to Clarice: he's directly addressing Dr Chilton by name.

Comment: Agreed. Well, *should* be crystal clear anyway.